# how to load c code variable into assembly code?

Tags: c++, assembly

I'm a beginner in assembly code, just learning.

in C/C++ (x64) code there are variables a and variable b and variable c (to accommodate the results of a+b), then how to call variables a and b in the assembly so that the addition operation can be occur?

Comment: read the doc again. you can follow here as well https://www.tutorialspoint.com/assembly_programming/assembly_arithmetic_instructions.htm

Comment: @roottraveller it only discuss about assembly, and i want to call assembly code in c code

Comment: Your question is too broad. There are many ways to integrate C and assembly depending on the circumstances. Maybe explain what you want to do specifically. You'll get better answers.

Comment: I suggest a more specific title if you just want to add 2 `int` variables with inline assembly.

Comment: variable names are essentially labels, if declared as global in C or C++ (separate languages) then other code (C, C++, assembly, etc) can then gain access to those variables/labels.   Just like one C function can use external variables from another C function.   And if you compile to assembly as well as disassemble a C function that uses an external variable you can see how that works in assembly language.  (reference the label basically)

Answer (score 1):

```
extern unsigned int a;
extern unsigned int b;

unsigned int fun ( void )
{
    return(a+b);
}
```

compile to assembly

```
movl    b(%rip), %eax
addl    a(%rip), %eax
ret
```

Understand that assembly language is specific to the tools not the target.  There are many, incompatible, assembly languages for x64 (and not talking about intel vs at&t that just multiplies the number).  But you can see that just like any other language including C or C++ themselves when you reference an external item you do it by name.  Which is essentially a label which is essentially an address.

So your syntax may vary based on the assembly language you are using (the assembler, the tool) but if I understand the question you reference the global variables by name.

```
   4:   8b 05 00 00 00 00       mov    0x0(%rip),%eax        # a <fun+0xa>
   a:   03 05 00 00 00 00       add    0x0(%rip),%eax        # 10 <fun+0x10>
  10:   c3                      retq
```

Note that compiling to assembly language can quite confusing based on the assembly language.  So it is also a good idea to disassemble tho object.   In this case, being an unlinked object, the tools have left the offset to these variables as zeros to be filled in by the linker later.  Which is exactly what you expect.  Depending on the instruction and instruction set you may get the address in the literal pool for a pc relative load that is then the address to the load/store/etc in question.  Or for variable length instruction sets like this the literal pool if you will is part of the instruction.

So then if I take

unsigned int a;
unsigned int b;

In another file, compile and link them both I get this:

```
Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000001000 <fun>:
    1000:   f3 0f 1e fa             endbr64 
    1004:   8b 05 f6 2f 00 00       mov    0x2ff6(%rip),%eax        # 4000 <b>
    100a:   03 05 f4 2f 00 00       add    0x2ff4(%rip),%eax        # 4004 <a>
    1010:   c3                      retq   
Disassembly of section .bss:

0000000000004000 <b>:
    4000:   00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
    ...

0000000000004004 <a>:
    4004:   00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
    ...
```

And the linker has filled in the offset/address to the "variables".

So you could now write that assembly code by hand and have it work.  If you are using this assembly language, otherwise figure out for the tool you are using the equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

create a separate c++ function for this job pass your variables and use assembly in that function to add those numbers then return their sum.

Function to add 2 c++ variables in assembly :

```
 int add(int a,int b){
    int result;
    __asm{
       mov eax,a         ;eax will contain value of a
       add eax,b         ;eax will contain sum of a and b 
       mov result,eax    ;value of eax is now stored in c++ variable result
    };
    return result;
 }
```

Use this function as:

```
int a=23;
int b=12;
int c=add(a,b);
```

Comment: Inline assembly is not supported in 64-bit Visual Studio, and this question is asking about `x64`.

Comment: VS style of inline assembly makes the function impossible to be *inlined*, and the register allocation for the surrounding code gets dirty. It is always better to use GCC/Clang's [extended asm](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html) when possible and something like this is necessary.

Comment: You are also just providing one possible option (which is also a bad one). The code gets different when the variables are *global*. Sometimes it's better to just write straight in assembly on a separate file.

Comment: @xiver77: This syntax is supported by clang with `-fasm-blocks`, but it's not a very good answer.  This syntax is necessarily inefficient, forcing store/reload of the inputs and store/reload of the output, even though function args and return values can go in registers.  And yeah, inline asm is compiler-specific, and this didn't say how to compile it.  (And the question doesn't say whether it's talking about local vars with inline asm, or global vars with separately compiled plain asm.)

Comment: @xiver77 we can use MASM if we want inline assembly in 64-bit VS